# OpenCV: assigning new values to matrix elements

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I am trying to read an image and assign some values of the read image to another new one using this code:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("001.jpg");
cv::cvtColor( source , source , CV_BGR2GRAY );
cv::Mat result = cv::Mat( source.rows, source.cols, source.type() );

int dx = 0; 
int dy = 0;
int len = 30;

for( int i = 0; i < source.cols - len; i ++ )
{
    dx = i + len;

    for( int j = 0; j < source.rows; j++ )
    {
        dy = j + 0.5 * dx;
        if( 0 <= dx && dx < source.cols && 0 <= dy && dy < source.rows )
        {
             result.at<uchar>(i,j) = source.at<uchar>(dx,dy);
        }
    }
}
```

But the code stops after running, without giving out any error message. I tried to debug it and suspect the line `result.at<uchar>(i,j) = source.at<uchar>(dx,dy)` is causing the problem. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the culprit is here:

```
 result.at<uchar>(i,j) = source.at<uchar>(dx,dy);
```

you got i,j as well as dx dy in reverse.

it's  `mat.at<type>(row,col);`   in opencv, not `mat.at<type>(x,y);`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `Berak` answer below i think you should do the following also

`Initialize result image with zeros:`   I feel that there is a problem. Your `dx` is getting incremented by `30` in each loop so, your that `for loop` will run only for few cases. But what should be the values in the cells of `result` which were not able to get filled during the `for loop`

Comment: Yes, I tried to show it using imshow. That is when it stops reacting.

Comment: if the condition satisfies then some of your pixels are getting the value but how about the pixels who didn't get any value....so initialize the `result` image so that every pixel have some value (atleast zero). And also reverse the order of `dx ` and `dy`

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the documentation is not very clear about this, the function `at` is used like this `cv::Mat::at(y,x)`. This is probably what caused the problem.

Also, to make your code more efficient, you should inverse your x and y loops like this :

```
for( int j = 0; j < source.rows; j ++ )
{

    for( int i = 0; i < source.cols- len; i++ )
    {
        dx = i + len;
        dy = j + 0.5*dx;
        if( 0 <= dx && dx < source.cols && 0 <= dy && dy < source.rows )
        {
             result.at<uchar>(j, i) = source.at<uchar>(dy, dx);
        }
    }
}
```

This is because in OpenCV, images are stored row-by-row, so defining the x loop as the inner loop is much faster.